# Не могу примонтировать папку в образе docker

Tags: linux, windows, docker, phpstorm, mount

Использую Docker Toolbox for Windows на Windows 8.1
В терминале phpstorm пытаюсь запустить команду:

```
docker run --rm -v /$(pwd)/manager/public:/var/www/html -p 8080:80 php:7.2-apache
```

Она вроде как успешно отрабатывает и контейнер запускается. Но проблема в том, что когда я захожу на http://192.168.99.100:8080/ то получаю ошибку апача: Forbidden, а в терминал мне прилетает это:

```
[autoindex:error] [pid 17] [client 192.168.99.1:52894] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index for
bidden by Options directive
```

т.е. в папке /var/www/html нет индексного файла, хотя в папке которую я монтирую ($(pwd)/manager/public) есть index.php. После проверки, оказывается, что папка /var/www/html действительно пустая.

Что я делаю не так?
Кстати `/$(pwd)/manager/public:/var/www/html` нагуглил [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540721/docker-toolbox-error-response-from-daemon-invalid-mode-root-docker) 
Без слэша контейнер не запускался. Команду pwd тоже добавил себе в windows, создав файл pwd.cmd, добавив в него `@echo %cd%` и разместив в `c:\windows\system32\`

Команды вроде

```
docker run --rm -v "%cd%/manager/public:/var/www/html" -p 8080:80 php:7.2-apache
```

выдают ошибку `docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /var/www/html.`

P.S. Возможно $(pwd) или %cd% выдают путь вроде C:\Users\Александр\ и возникает конфликт с двоеточием? Только вот как это обойти? Даже попытки использовать абсолютный путь не приводят к успеху - контейнер не запускается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй команду

```
docker run --rm -v //D_DRIVE/work/5_ject-manager/manager/public:/var/www/html -p 8080:80 php:7.3-apache
```

путь замени на свой. Но перед этим в VirtualBox Менеджер добавь диск D:\ под именем D_DRIVE, в "общие папки"